# Why use `virtual` when declaring an ActionResult

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I was looking over some code from a `MVC3 nuget` package, and I noticed that some methods in the controller used `virtual`, like `public virtual ActionResult WhatEver()` and the others where how I have always seen then, `public ActionResult WhatEver2()`.

Why would someone do this? What are the benefits?

Comment: Can you tell us which "MVC3 nuget package" are you talking about?

Comment: Do you know what the `virtual` keyword is used for?

Comment: @nemesv I will tomorrow when I'm back on that machine, it was some membership panel/backend I think. (I had looked at several ones so I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: @Daniel Mann, it's used to allow it to be overridden, or in Entity, it is used for lazy loading, right? Am I wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only possible benefit is that you can override that method in an inheriting class.

It's hard to say what the specific benefits of that are without knowing details about the library and this method's place within it.  Say it's a CMS library and the ActionResult returns a dialog box.  Marking that method virtual might allow you (the consumer of the library) to subclass the controller and modify the dialog's behavior in some way.

Comment: Hmm, I'll have to look at it again, (and probably add it to my question,) but I suppose that could be why. It just struck me as odd when I saw it, and now that I got home and am done working I thought I'd ask. I absolutely have to go back and look at it and what it does/how it could be overridden. Thanks! Is that somewhat common in a MVC Controller?

Comment: I would say uncommon, it would be more common in an entity class or something.   Still possible though, I guess if you really really feel like doing ti that way.